# Databricks Community Edition Server error: Workspace quota exceeded (using 106 of 100 MB allowed)

Tags: azure-databricks

Whenever I attempt to do literally anything with Databricks Notebooks on Databricks Community Edition I get the following error:

> Server error: Workspace quota exceeded (using 106 of 100 MB allowed).
> You must delete some items from your Workspace, such as notebooks, to
> continue.

However, I have deleted a whole bunch of notebooks from my Workspace and have deleted files in the /tmp folder and /var folder, but I'm still getting the error.

I checked the following site for guidance [http://mariuszrafalo.pl/sgh/projekty/db_clean.html#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20main%20reasons,up%20files%20to%20restore%20service%20](http://mariuszrafalo.pl/sgh/projekty/db_clean.html#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20main%20reasons,up%20files%20to%20restore%20service%20).

I execute the following code I get the following output

```
%sh
du --human-readable --max-depth=1 --exclude='/dbfs' /

du: cannot read directory '/proc/1243/task/1243/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot read directory '/proc/1243/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot access '/proc/1246/task/1246/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1246/task/1246/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1246/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1246/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0   /proc
108K    /run
36K /home
4.0K    /srv
2.6G    /usr
0   /dev
2.7G    /databricks
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /boot
5.0M    /etc
1.6G    /var
135M    /opt
86M /root
du: cannot read directory '/sys/kernel/security/integrity': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/sys/kernel/debug': Permission denied
0   /sys
180K    /tmp
16K /mnt
4.0K    /Workspace
14M /local_disk0
7.0G    /
```

You will notice that /usr and /var folders are large, I attempted to delete the files in the folders with the following code:

```
dbutils.fs.rm('/usr', True)
```

But it didn't help with the error.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated as I'm able to use Databricks Community edition to carry out my training

Not able to see trash
My folder in users
[image]

Comment: have you emptied a Trash?

Comment: Hi Alex, that is good question. How do you empty the trash in the Community Edition?

Comment: Although, I don't think the problem will be resolved by emptying the trash

Comment: Any additional thoughts from anyone on this problem?

Comment: Click on triangle on the trash directory in your directory in workspace

Comment: I think I must be going crazy because I don't see the trash directory from the triangle ... see the image I posted in the original question

Comment: You need to go to your own directory in Users, there will be the Trash  folder - click on triangle on it

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being an idiot here, I have uploaded an image of the directory Users, but as you can see there is no Trash folder - dont forget I'm talking about Databricks Community Edition here.

Answer (score 0):

**Permanently purge workspace storage**

Deleted notebooks, folders, libraries, and experiments are recoverable from the trash for 30 days. This action permanently purges deleted notebooks, folders, libraries, and experiments. Once purged, workspace objects are not recoverable.

After deleting any notebooks that contain any personal data, you must also delete job runs that have been run against the notebook, as they may contain similar information. This may be done manually via the jobs interface or via API.

Runs associated with purged experiments are also purged, as well as metrics, params, and tags associated with the runs. However, you must manually delete artifacts associated with the runs. For example, you can delete artifacts stored on DBFS using the DBFS REST API.

Note: Queries and Dashboards in Databricks SQL will not be deleted. If you want to do so, go to Admin Console and give yourself the Databricks SQL access entitlement first.
[image]

**Permanently purge all revision history**

This action purges revision history saved before the selected timeframe for all notebooks in the workspace. Once purged, revision history is not recoverable.

**Permanently purge cluster logs**

This action permanently purges Spark driver logs and historical metrics snapshots for all clusters in the workspace. Once purged, logs and snapshots are non-recoverable.

Refer - [Manage workspace storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/workspace/storage)

Comment: Hi @AbhishekKhandave-MT, thanks for reaching out. I 'Permanently purge workspace storage' but I'm still getting the error ""'Server error: Workspace quota exceeded (using 106 of 100 MB allowed). You must delete some items from your Workspace, such as notebooks, to continue.'"" whenever I try to add a new cell in a notebook. Should I 'Purge revision history' as well? Thanks

Comment: Seriously, any further help with this problem will be really appreciated. I'm still getting the same error .. please.

Comment: ok, so I have completely purged all the workspaces as suggested above, but still getting the same error.. I'm really needing some help with this...

Comment: Have you tried with purge cluster logs and purge all revision history ?

Comment: thanks for sticking with me on this issue. I purged the revision history last night. I have just this minute purged the cluster logs. Is there a timeframe before purging takes effect? Because after just purging the cluster logs, I'm still getting the same error message. Please note I'm getting the error even without spinning up the cluster

Comment: @Patterson , You can configure your workspace to store all interactive notebook results in your Azure subscription, rather than the control plane.  Please try this workaround https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/workspace/storage#--configure-the-storage-location-for-interactive-notebook-results

Comment: are you suggesting that the problem is solely caused by the number of notebooks in my workspace? Because I have been deleting a whole bunch of folders where notebooks are stored and I'm still getting the same error